# How do I order the results of rails geocoder gem by something other than distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-geocoder

I have this excellent gem https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder working fine in my app but I need to order the results of an active record query slightly differently.

For example using the rails console

```
$> Person.near('London',10)
```

produces a long SQL query (not relevant) followed by

```
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

This gives a nice ordered list of People from closest to furthest (upto 10 miles away). Now if I do this

```
$> Person.near('London',10).order('price_per_hour')
```

The query is appended by

```
ORDER BY distance ASC, price_per_hour
```

I still want all the people near London but I dont want it ordering by distance. There doesnt seem to be anyway of taking this out.

I can't sort outside of the active record query because I am using pagination so ordering needs to be done in the main query which is then paginated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should try [`reorder`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reorder) instead of `order` :

```
Person.near('London',10).reorder('price_per_hour')
```

The `reorder` removes and replace the `order` statement created by the scope `near`.

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late.
Now `geocoder` gem provides to remove default order of distance

```
Person.near('London',10,order: false).order('price_per_hour')
```